# Printing on "standard out" and "standard error"

Tags: io-redirection, stdout

I'm puzzled over some terminology used in my homework:

So, the way I understand the question is that I should print `echo`, `cat`, etc., which I would do like with the `echo` command, for example

```
echo echo
echo cat 
echo ´!!´
```

Is that what is meant by "is printed on standard out"?. Am I on the right track here?

Then, I don't know what is meant by "nothing is printed on standard error when the command is entered".

Comment: `And, yes, "nothing more" in the output means "nothing more".`, does your teacher mean that there shouldn't be a newline at the end of the string `blotz`?

Comment: @Terdon given the requirement I suspect it would be tricky - if not impossible - for at least one of the commands to output the text without a newline. It's a good catch though

Comment: @roaima not at all. We're allowed to use extra commands as well so we could just parse it out.

Comment: The edit-history has the wording of the actual homework assignment, which the OP took out so google wouldn't find this.  This leaves the question very unclear, so look at the history.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you should interpret this homework as meaning that you need to output the word *blotz* using each of the commands `echo`, `cat`, `ls`, `grep`, and `!!` in turn.

The trivial case is `echo blotz` of course.

The `cat` command can be considered to output the contents of a file. ([`man cat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) may be helpful here.) Your homework permits you to prepare a file beforehand for you to output, so again this should be very straightforward.

The others will take some thinking about to achieve the necessary result.

Comment: Dear roaima, thank you for your response. So just to make sure I understand, with `cat` for example, I could create a text file with the text _blotz_ on it, and then i say cat textFileName...like that?

Comment: @Haz that would work, yes.

Comment: Sukminder....interesting, so they were trying to trick us there I guess. If I just say `echo blotz`  it will still print the newline character, which it seems they don't want

Comment: Hello again @roaima .  I created a text file with _blotz_ on it, so i I say `grep blotz textFileName` , then it prints _blotz_ . Pretty similar in easiness to "cat" but you said this would require more thinking, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The question tells you to use each of a list of commands and make that command print the string `blotz` and nothing else. If your teacher wants to have a newline printed after each `blotz` (which is not clear from your question), you could do:

```
$ echo "blotz"
blotz
$ echo "blotz" > file && cat file
blotz
$ touch blotz && ls blotz
blotz
$ echo blotz | grep b  ## This might also include (invisible) color codes
blotz
$ echo blotz | grep --color=never b ## This one avoids the color codes
blotz
```

Using `!!` is trickier since, by default, it will also print the command run. For example:

```
$ blotz      ## run blotz to get that saved as !!
blotz: command not found
$ echo !!  ## print the value of !!
echo blotz ## Unfortunately, this also prints the command being run. 
blotz
```

To get around that, you could make a little script:

```
set -o histexpand
set -o history

blotz
echo !!
```

And then run it like so:

```
$ bash foo.sh 2> /dev/null 
blotz
```

There might be a clever hack for this using subshells but I haven't been able to find it.

---

If your teacher doesn't even want the newline, use these instead:

```
$ echo -n "blotz"
$ echo -n "blotz" > file && cat file
$ touch blotz && ls blotz | tr -d $'\n'
$ echo blotz | grep --color=never b | tr -d $'\n'
```

And for the `!!` script:

```
$ bash foo.sh 2> /dev/null | tr -d $'\n'
```

Comment: thank you very much! I´m new to this website, and so far I've learned linux basics. I think to this point in the hw, we are not supposed to use scripts just yet (that is the next part of the hw). I was thinking I could get rid of the undesired output that `!!`produces by only selecting the second line of the output, do you know how to do that? Thanks