# print last line of !! command

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, text-processing, sed

so I want to be able to print *helloworld* using the `!!` command. I tried creating a text file with the text *helloworld* on it. Then I say

```
cat textFileName
```

It prints *helloworld*. Then I say

```
!!
```

and it prints

*cat textFileName*
*helloworld*

I tried using `tail` but it didn't work. I want to write commands in such a way that !! is used and only *helloworld* is printed.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the !! command -- it repeats your previous command.

Comment: I don't believe you can. As `echo -e "Hello\nworld" | awk "NR==2"` prints `world`, doing `echo -e "Hello\nworld"` then `!! | awk "NR==2"` outputs `echo -e "Hello\nworld" | awk "NR==2"`
`world`. We can see what is happening is that the `!!` command is repeating your previous command, and showing you what it was too

Comment: My exercise is asking me to use !! and _helloworld_ should be printed to the output

Comment: It IS being printed to the output

Comment: yep but my exercise says NOTHING ELSE should be printed to the output. I want to get rid of that first line of output

Comment: so you want to run `cat textFileName` yet you don't want it to show in the console, which means the command wont run, so either way `cat textFileName` will show in the output because it is the command you are running, and if it didn't show in the output then the command wont run...phew

Comment: @gwillie I do not understand what you are saying

Comment: gwillie, that was a lot to take in (pun had to be made). @Haz, willie is saying that you completed the task and you're making the problem harder than you have to.

Comment: Steven. No I am not

Comment: Haz, read Eric's post. You can see that he is even demonstrating to you that the repeat of the command with the substitution is not part of the standard output stream, which is why you can't redirect it. This is also why the example I showed didn't "work". Maybe you should type out the exact wording of the question you were given so we understand better.

Comment: BTW, if you do `ls` then `!! > test.txt` test.txt will show the outputs of the ls command and not show the full command.

Comment: Well we've shown that we can redirect standard output and standard error and the command will repeat. So tbh I don't know how to get rid of the command repeat.

Comment: See [Printing on “standard out” and “standard error”](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227782/printing-on-standard-out-and-standard-error) for the exact homework question to which this relates

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jeff's comment, it repeats the previous command and at least on all the bashes I've used it will also print out the the command for you to see what you just did, which might explain the `cat textFileName` that you're seeing.  That output is writen to the ternminal, not printed to stdout or stderr.  For example:

```
$ cat textFile
helloworld

$ !!
cat textFile
helloworld

$ !! &>/dev/null
cat textFile &>/dev/null
```

So that line being printed is just displayed to you for your help, it's not part of the output that would show up in, say, a pipeline if you used `!!`

Comment: HI Eric thank you for the response. I'm a newbish to Linux so  I don't really understand those two last lines you put.
`$ !! &>/dev/null
cat textFile &>/dev/null`

Comment: As you know, !! will repeat the previous command, but you don't have to leave it unchanged.  !! will expand to the previous command, and in this case I'm adding `&>/dev/null` which will send all output from both stdout and stderr to /dev/null, which just throws it away. I did that to show that you would still see the command being run after the !! expands, because that is not being written to stdout or stderr

Answer (score 0):

I was "inspired" this afternoon by the updated requirement:

> Use the !! command such that helloworld (and nothing more) is printed
>   on standard out, and nothing is printed on standard error when the
>   command is entered. You can precede your command with other commands
>   (e.g., to create a file, run other commands, etc.) and/or pass options
>   or arguments to your commands. And yes, nothing more means nothing
>   more.

...which seems sufficiently made-up for me to suggest this answer/workaround:

```
exec ksh
PS1="helloworld"
!! 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Dear Jeff, thanks for you response. First I tried `exec ksh`, and it said _bash : exec : kWh : not found_

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure things out.

I could be in a folder with no files on it, then I create an alias

```
alias helloworld=ls
```

then I call

```
helloworld
```

then I call `!!`

and all that would be printed would be

*helloworld*

Thanks all!

Comment: Crafty, but not correct. The requirement say you are to print to *"standard out"*, or `stdout`. Your final *"helloworld"* is *not* printed to stdout. As per *this question* it is OK, but not if you are to adhere to the requirements in http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227782/28489

Comment: As the *echoed command* from `!!` is not printed to stdout nor stderr the  criteria is however filled, even with the output from e.g. `echo -n blotz` followed by `!!`.

Comment: So you are saying that my answer is not correct yet. I definitely want to fulfill the requirements in [link](unix.stackexchange.com/q/227782/28489)

I'm overall confused by the "standard output" thing. I thought anything that is printed is standard output

Comment: How about the shorter: `helloworld; !! 2>/dev/null`;     No aliases -- the first "command" results (presumably) in a "command not found" error, followed by the history repeat which drops the error off.

Comment: Nevermind - just tried my own suggestion.  Another idea to generalize the above answer: `alias helloworld=:` -- then it doesn't matter if there are files in the current directory.

Comment: @JeffSchaller do you think my approach is correct?

Comment: @Haz I think it's an odd problem to solve, but this idea of making a "null" alias is the best path I see so far.